# UIKeyCommand Arrow Key Input Not Working

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uikeycommand

I have other UIKeyCommand's working properly, however the arrow key (using UIKeyInput[Direction]Arrow constants) selectors are not getting called. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

This is the code I am using to create an arrow key command:

```
UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyInputRightArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(moveRight))
```

The `moveRight` selector is not getting called, nor are any arrow key selectors. Other UIKeyCommands, other than arrow keys, are working as expected.

Comment: Has anyone solve this??